# Livewire old values for dynamic arrays as part of a parent form

Tags: laravel-livewire

I'm working with livewire and need to preserve old values of a dynamic array (add/delete fields), inserted as a subform, when validation fails from another part of the form.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok. There's not much to go on here. What problems are you facing, what have you tried so far, what isn't working? This question is likely going to be closed due to lack of information.

Comment: what you mean 'preserve old values''. do you want to display the existing information pass to some fields. please clarify

Answer (score 0):

I need to preserve data already entered in the inputs, by means of an inserted livewire block, when a field of the container form fails in the validation. It turns out that when you return, the data entered in the livewire form is lost. Thanks for your help!

The place where I insert livewire tag...

```
...

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="numbers_per_line" 
           class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">
        {{ __('Cantidad de números por línea (9 o 10)') }}
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input class="form-control" 
               type="number" min="9" max="10" 
               name="numbers_per_line" 
               value="{{ old('numbers_per_line') ?? 
                      $bingo->numbers_per_line }}" 
               required>
    </div>
</div>

@livewire('bingo-draw', ['bingo' => $bingo])

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="card_price" 
           class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">
        {{ __('Precio del cartón') }}
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input class="form-control" 
               type="number" min="1.00" 
               step="0.01" name="card_price" 
               value="{{ old('card_price') ?? $bingo->card_price }}" 
               required>
    </div>
</div>

...
```

The code of livewire inserted is the following:

```
<div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="number_of_draws" 
               class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">
            {{ __('Cantidad de premios en el sorteo final') }}
        </label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input class="form-control" type="number" min="1" 
                   name="number_of_draws"
                   wire:model="numberOfDraws"
                   value="{{ old('number_of_draws') ?? 
                         $numberOfDraws }}" 
                   required readonly="" disabled="true">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-auto w-full">
                <thead>
                    <th class="col-md-1 text-left">Nro. Sorteo</th>
                    <th class="col-md-7 text-left">Descripción</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2 text-left">
                        Valor del premio en pesos</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2 text-left" width="100"></th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @php $i = 0; @endphp
                    @foreach($drawsArray as $drawElement)
                        <tr>
                            <td class="p-1" valign="top">
                                <input class="form-control" type="number" 
                                       min="1" name="draw_number[]"
                                       value="{{ old('draw_number.'.$i) 
                                              ?? 
                                              $drawElement['draw_number'] 
                                              }}" 
                                       required readonly />
                            </td>
                            <td class="p-1" valign="top">
                                <textarea class="md-textarea form-control"
                                          name="draw_description[]" 
                                          rows="2" required 
                                >{{ old('draw_description.'.$i) ?? 
                                    $drawElement['draw_description'] }} 
                                </textarea>
                            </td>
                            <td class="p-1" valign="top">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" 
                                       name="draw_prize[]" 
                                       value="{{ old('draw_prize.'.$i) ?? 
                                              $drawElement['draw_prize'] 
                                              }}" 
                                       required />
                            </td>
                            <td class="p-1" valign="top">
                                <button wire:click="removeDraw({{ 
                                        $drawElement['draw_number'] }})"
                                        type="button" 
                                        class="btn btn-warning">
                                    Eliminar
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @php $i++; @endphp
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-1">
                @error('newDescription')
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        {{ $message }}
                    </div>
                @enderror
                <textarea class="md-textarea form-control"
                          name="new_description"
                          rows="2" wire:model.lazy="newDescription" 
                          placeholder="Ingrese nuevo premio..."> 
                </textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @error('newPrize')
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        {{ $message }}
                    </div>
                @enderror
                <input class="form-control" type="text"
                    name="new_prize" 
                    placeholder="Importe..."
                    wire:model.lazy="newPrize">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button wire:click="addDraw" 
                        type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                    Agregar premio
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally, the code of the mount function:

```
public function mount(Bingo $bingo){
    $this->numberOfDraws = old('numberOfDraws') ?? 
                           $bingo>number_of_draws;
    $this->draws = $bingo->draws;
    $this->currentBingo = $bingo;

    if(old('numberOfDraws')){
        for($i = 0; $i <= $this->numberOfDraws; $i++){
            $this->drawsArray[] = [
                'draw_number' => old('draw_number.'.$i),
                'draw_description' => old('draw_description.'.$i),
                'draw_prize' => old('draw_prize.'.$i),
            ];
        }
    }else{
        foreach($this->draws as $draw){
            $this->drawsArray[] = [
                'draw_number' => $draw->draw_number,
                'draw_description' => $draw->description,
                'draw_prize' => $draw->prize,
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

The function addDraw keeps the values of draw_number in order, but if the validation fails I lost the old values...

I apologize if I'm not clear enough... my english is not very well, and is the first time I post some question here.
Thanks!